Flutter and Firebase
Whats wrong with my code here?? The button is expected to delete the car data from the user's specific car collection as well as from the global car collection.
trailing: IconButton(
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      String carsId = doc.id; // Document ID of the car in the global collection
                                      try {
                                        // Check if the 'userCarId' field exists in the document before using it
                                        String userCarId = carData['userCarId'] ?? '';

                                        if (userCarId.isEmpty) {
                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                            const SnackBar(content: Text('No userCarId found in this car document')),
                                          );
                                          return;
                                        }
                                        
                                        // Delete from the user's specific collection using userCarId
                                        await _firestore
                                            .collection('Users')
                                            .doc(currentUser!.email)
                                            .collection('Cars')
                                            .doc(userCarId) // Use the userCarId to identify the document in the user's collection
                                            .delete();

                                        // Delete from the global Cars collection
                                        await _firestore.collection('Cars').doc(carsId).delete();

                                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                          const SnackBar(content: Text('Vehicle deleted successfully')),
                                        );
                                      } catch (e) {
                                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                          const SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to delete vehicle')),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),

The userCarId is called from this progam
// Adding vehicle to the user's specific collection first
      DocumentReference userCarRef = await _firestore.collection('Users').doc(userEmail).collection('Cars').add({
        'brand': brand,
        'model': model,
        'price': price,
        'transmission': transmission,
        'seats': seats,
        'mileage': mileage,
        'fuelType': fuelType,
        'registrationNumber': registrationNumber,
        'carType': carType,
        'imageURL': imageUrl, // Save the image URL
      });

      // After the vehicle is added to the user's collection, retrieve its document ID
      String userCarId = userCarRef.id;

      // Now add the vehicle to the global 'Cars' collection and set 'userCarId' to the user's car document ID
      await _firestore.collection('Cars').add({
        'brand': brand,
        'model': model,
        'price': price,
        'transmission': transmission,
        'seats': seats,
        'mileage': mileage,
        'fuelType': fuelType,
        'registrationNumber': registrationNumber,
        'carType': carType,
        'owner': userEmail,
        'imageURL': imageUrl, // Save the image URL
        'userCarId': userCarId, // Set the document ID of the user's specific car entry
      });

I tried changing variables and so on you can see my firebase storage, this is the global car collection.


When I press the delete icon, the 1st snackbar pops up i.e. No userCarId found
